# Calibrating two color sensors?

Tags: c, sensors

I need to calibrate two color sensors, but unfortunately they seem to differ hardware wise (the model is the same, the reflection of the light shined from them is different, one is brighter) as they measure different values in the same exact conditions.

So, I've thought of 'normalizing' one.

Basically, when I calibrate the sensor, I get the ratio needed to calculate the proportion.

Here's an example:

```
// lx_sensor_red -> 310
// rx_sensor_red -> 250
// Again, remember they are sitting on the same color, under the same lighting

float rx_red_ratio = ((float)lx_sensor_red)/((float)rx_sensor_red); // Not sure if I use too many parenthesis

// I do this for green and blue too

...  
... 

int rx_red;
get_sensor_value(0, rx_sensor, &rx_red);
rx_red = (int)(rx_red * rx_red_ratio);

// And so on..
```

I'm wondering, is this suitable? It seems to work, but I am not sure if there's a better method or if this might fail under certain conditions?

Comment: Better to calibrate across the range using a number of points, as their performance might not be linear. It depends on how accurate you want it.

Comment: @WeatherVane how would I do that?

Comment: One point calibration is only calibrating an offset. Two point can calibrate offset and gain. But you seem to calibrate the gain using one point.... If I understand what you are doing here at all.

Comment: You mean calibrate or interpret? To calibrate build an array of ratios across the  range. To interpret interpolate a ratio (using the reference instrument). But as @EugeneSh. points out, an offset and a ratio is sometimes used.

Comment: @WeatherVane So basically, I need to do exactly what I am doing, multiple times on different colors, and then make an average?

Comment: I mean make an array of the correction factors at N points across the range. Then figure out what the correction factor need to be applied by interpolating from the array.

Comment: Could you write an example?

Comment: How accurately do you need the sensors to be calibrated? What are you using them for? Colorimetry is complicated; there's probably books about this topic alone.

Comment: @duskwuff I need them for  a PID controller.